# Sufficiency of $\bar{X}$ in a Binomial$(2,p)$ population.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$ be a random sample from a $\text{Bin}(2,p)$ population.  Use the definition of sufficiency to show that the sample mean is sufficient for $p$.

Here I am not allowed to use the Neyman Factorization Theorem.  By definition, $\overline{X}$ is sufficient for $p$ if $P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,...,X_n=x_n|\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k)$ does not depend on $p$.

Now 
\begin{align*}
P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,...,X_n=x_n&|\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k)\\&=\frac{ P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,...,X_n=x_n,\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k)}{P(\overline{X}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k)}\\
&=\frac{P(X_1=x_1)P(X_2=x_2)...P(X_n=x_n)}{P(\overline{X}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k)}\\
&=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2}{x_k}p^{x_k}(1-p)^{2-x_k}}{P(\overline{X}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k)}
\end{align*}

Here I am just plain stuck.  I don't know the distribution of $\bar{X}$.  I tried assuming it was normal and I couldn't get anywhere,  I need to cancel all $p$'s out of this nasty expression.

Comment: A short cut: You are working with an exponential family. So sample mean should be suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that $$P\left(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,...,X_n=x_n\Big|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k=t\right)$$ does not depend on $p$ (in your expression this $t$ is absent). Now the term in the condition is equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^nX_k=nt$ but $\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$ is binomially distributed with parameters $2n$ and $p$, in symbols $$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k \sim B(2n,p)$$ Hence

$$\begin{align*}
P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n|\overline{X}=t)&=\frac{P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,...,X_n=x_n,S_n=nt)}{P(S_n=nt)}=
\\&=\frac{P(X_1=x_1)P(X_2=x_2)...P(X_n=x_n)}{P(S_n=nt)}=\\
&=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2}{x_k}p^{x_k}(1-p)^{2-x_k}}{\binom{2n}{t}p^{t}(1-p)^{2n-t}}=\\&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2}{x_k}p^{t}(1-p)^{2n-t}}{\binom{2n}{t}p^{t}(1-p)^{2n-t}}=\dfrac{\binom{2}{x_1}\binom{2}{x_2}\ldots\binom{2}{x_n}}{\binom{2n}{t}}\end{align*}$$ which does not depend on $p$.

Comment: Good work! I would do that same.